# How to read response from Client-Server Socket Connection?

Tags: java, android, sockets

I am executing shell commands from my Android APP. I am able to execute the command but unable to read the response from Server.
My code is as follows :

```
public String executeThroughSocket(int portNo, String portAddress, String command) throws IOException {

    StringBuilder responseString = new StringBuilder();

    PrintWriter writer = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    Socket clientSocket = null;

    try {
        clientSocket = new Socket(portAddress, portNo);
        if (!clientSocket.isConnected())
            throw new SocketException("Could not connect to Socket");

        clientSocket.setKeepAlive(true);

        writer = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
        writer.println(command);
        writer.flush();

        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
        String str;
        while ((str = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            responseString.append(str);
        }

    } finally {
        if (writer != null)
            writer.close();
        if (bufferedReader != null)
            bufferedReader.close();
        if (clientSocket != null)
            clientSocket.close();
    }
    return responseString.toString();
}
```

Comment: is the server, which executes your command, written by you? if yes can you post that code as well. Seems blocking is happening

Comment: add some debug output or run in debug and highlight the line where it's hanging. Most likely something like readLine() never finding end-of-line or the like

Comment: @premkumar server is not developed by me. I think from server side nothing is reflected to be read. for debugging : bufferedReader.readLine() is returning null.

Comment: well - if there's nothing send from server, you cannot read it.

Comment: its my guess. I don't have source of code of server, so can't really be sure server is reflecting or not.

Comment: if you are getting bufferedReader.readLine() as null, then server has no message to send in response. If your program is stuck at bufferedReader.readLine()  while loop line then either try closing output stream or there must be a particular end of message format you must send. This end of message should be in docs if there is any. is your program stuck at while loop or returned response is null?

Comment: @premkumar bufferedReader.readLine() is returning null. Got it, server has no message to send.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with my code. It was the server that was not sending any response.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set timeout for socket

clientSocket .setSoTimeout(5000); // milisekundy

Comment: You should explain, why your code snippet helps to improve the answer.

Comment: Adding a timeout don't get you the response, just raise a timeout exception.